# Flyout menu with scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, suckerfish, flyout

I'm trying to create a flyout menu that has scrolling build in if its larger than the screen.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this with the native overflow-y scrolling properties.  Everytime I seem to set that overflow-y:auto then the the menu that flys out is nested within the parent div with a scroll bar.

Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If you could post an example of how it's failing (upload it somewhere) I'll have a look for you :)

Cheers,

Iain

Comment: Yeah, we could definitely use an example, even a screenshot would help but a live page or the code would be better

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution of mine, but you can try this.. it has a really nice effect and serves your purpose:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns//

Answer (score 0):

you should set the max-height proparty for the div otherwise it cant tell (since it is sort of absolutely positioned) where to stop, or u can set the height for older browsers, or you can javascript it, change height dynamically until it reaches a maximum